# Double.TryParse() ignores NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double

I'd like to know if I'm missing something or not... I'm running under the standard Great British culture.

```
Double result = 0;
if (Double.TryParse("1,2,3", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
{
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Expected output would be nothing... "1,2,3" shouldn't parse as a double. However it does. According to the .NET 2.0 [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> AllowThousands    Indicates that the numeric string can have group
>   separators; for example, separating the hundreds from the thousands.
>   Valid group separator characters are determined by the
>   NumberGroupSeparator and CurrencyGroupSeparator properties of
>   NumberFormatInfo and the number of digits in each group is determined
>   by the NumberGroupSizes and CurrencyGroupSizes properties of
>   NumberFormatInfo.

Allow thousands is included in NumberStyles.Any. The NumberGroupSizes is 3 for my culture. Is this just a bug in the Double.Parse? seems unlikely but I can't spot what I'm doing wrong....

Comment: This might be why I got a valid result when testing [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014535/float-parse-doesnt-work-the-way-i-wanted/1014559#1014559) on a similar question.

Comment: Just curious, but what is the value of result?

Comment: I think you'd have to ask Microsoft if its a bug but, I get the same behaviour as you. Can always do `NumberStyles.Any ^ NumberStyles.AllowThousands` but that's not much use if you are expecting legitmate groups of three.

Comment: 1,,,,,2,3 will also parse as 123. It seems that the `CurrencyGroupSeparator` character is completely ignored in parsing.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: As Magnus points out, it parses as "123.0".

Comment: Here i've shared my solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41916721/3930528

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means the input string can contain zero or more instances of `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator`. This separator can be used to separate groups of numbers of any size; not just thousands. `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator` and `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes` are used when formatting decimals as strings. Using Reflector it seems like `NumberGroupSeparator` is only used to determine if the character is a separator, and if it is, it is skipped. `NumberGroupSizes` is not used at all.

If you want to validate the string, you could do so using RegEx or write a method to do so. Here's one I just hacked together:

```
string number = "102,000,000.80";
var parts = number.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    var len = parts[i].Length;
    if ((len != 3) && (i == parts.Length - 1) && (parts[i].IndexOf('.') != 3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parts[i]);
    }
}

// Respecting Culture
static Boolean CheckThousands(String value)
{
    String[] parts = value.Split(new string[] { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (String part in parts)
    {
        int length = part.Length;
        if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes.Contains(length) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1, it appears `NumberGroupSizes` is ignored on parsing (internal method is `Number.ParseNumber`).

Comment: I'd just started digging in with Reflector but hadn't the time to get that far down as yet. I'm considering using a Regex actually, but I need to be careful and ensure it's all still culture aware.

Comment: @Ian You could build your Regex expressions based on the information stored in NumberFormatInfo for each culture.

Comment: Yes indeed, think that's what I'm going to do :) Just wanted to make other people aware of that fact.

Comment: I added a culture aware option. Actually though for anyone using this it's a little more complicated. You want to only look at numeric characters (ignore -,£,$ etc) and you want to stop at the decimal point or whatever separator is used in the culture.

Comment: The culture specific version fails for 12,345 - got me started though, so thanks