# How can I parse only the float number from the string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    string curItem = item.ToString();
    var parts = curItem.Split("{}XY=, ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var xCoord = float.Parse(parts[0]);
    var yCoord = float.Parse(parts[1]);
    var point = new PointF(xCoord, yCoord);
    CloudEnteringAlert.pointtocolor.Add(point);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

The curItem variable contains value like that: `Cloud detected at: 0.9174312 Kilometers from the coast.`

I want to get only the *0.9174312* from value and set to be in the variable xCoord.
The problem is that the way it is doing the parsing now i'm getting error:

`Input string was not in a correct format`

The index should not be zero, I guess. How can I get only the float number from the string?

And this strings formats for now are the same each time:

**First part:** `Cloud detected at: Second part: 0.9174312 and Last part: Kilometers from the coast.`

But maybe in the future I will change the string format so i need that in any place the float number will be in the middle last or start of the string to get only the float number.

Comment: you should get string between : and Kilometers then trim it.

Comment: I tried float.Parse("0.9174312") it is converting fine. May be your string having space. Try this parts[0].Trim() .

Comment: Check the following link [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014535/float-parse-doesnt-work-the-way-i-wanted)

Comment: TryParse is your friend. :)

Comment: @SeeTheC: On my machine `float.Parse("0.9174312")` would yield `9174312`. Ignoring culture when parsing numbers is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks  @Joey . I was not knowing culture in floating point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using regular expressions.

```
var match = Regex.Match(val, @"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)");
if (match.Success)
  xCoord = Convert.ToSingle(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: You should probably give `ToSingle` the correct culture, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply extract the float from the string by using Regular Expressions:

```
string xCoord = Regex.Match(curItem, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+").Groups[1].Value;
```

After that, you can parse it to a float.

More info about regular expressions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), or you could take a look at the [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) page from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            string curItem = item.ToString();
            var parts = curItem.Split("{}XY=, ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var xCoord = CultureCheck(parts[0]);
            var yCoord = CultureCheck(parts[1]);
            var point = new PointF(xCoord, yCoord);
            CloudEnteringAlert.pointtocolor.Add(point);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }       


    private double CultureCheck(string input)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
       return double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.Any, ci);
    }
```