# C# convert string to float containing both "," and "."

Tags: c#, string, formatting, format

I'm parsing a xml file containing strings like "91.899,74" (which is the correct format in my country) which I would like to convert into a float using float.Parse() but I can't get it to work without replacing "." with "" and "," with "."

If I don't do the replacements I get input was not in the correct format exception.

Any ideas on how to do the convert ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use your culture settings:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de");
double number = Double.Parse("202.667,40", culture);
```

[float.Parse() doesn't work the way I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014535/float-parse-doesnt-work-the-way-i-wanted)

[Double parse with culture format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109816/double-parse-with-culture-format)

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with money use `Decimal` rather than `Double`, and _especially_ rather than `float`.