# C# - float.parse ignores dot

Tags: c#, string, parsing, mvvm

I have a textbox, that is binded to a string variable. The input is 5.5
I need the string variable to calculate something but i noticed that float.parse(stringvariable) ignores the dot (makes it a 55).

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give a [mre]? What is your Culture setting?

Comment: Try entering `5,5` instead.

Comment: check out a non exhaustive list of decimal separator from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) some use comma, other periods. Your app is running on a computer that has the culture set to one of those country.

Comment: Use the [overload method that accepts a culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Single_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and pass the correct culture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [float.Parse() doesn't work the way I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014535/float-parse-doesnt-work-the-way-i-wanted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to your default culture info. To accept decimal points which are `.` then can do this:

```
float f = float.Parse("float value as string", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However if you're expecting `,` to be used then you can specify then you can specify a culture which does that like this:

```
float f = float.Parse("float value as string", new CultureInfo("fr-FR").NumberFormat);
```

Obviously can be any culture and don't have to use French!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a comma is considered the thousands separator for the invariant culture.

Comment: Yes that is very correct, have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Tom Dee, this issue is related to your System.Globalization.CultureInfo settings.

You can modify this for the current thread by setting:

- CurrentCulture
- CurrentUICulture

i.e.

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

or

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT");
```

to the CultureInfo object you need, as well as use the correct overload for the Parse method, previously highlighted.